# UISearchController - Keyboard not showing

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uisearchcontroller

I am using the UISearchController and the search function works except for two things. Perhaps they are related:
a) The keyboard does not show. So I cannot press the "Search" button
b) In my main TableView I access the prototype cell that has the style "Subtitle". When the search is going on, the cell that shows is "Basic" style. In both cases (TableViewController and SearchViewController) I use the same cell identifier.

Any ideas? Here some of the code:

```
class OverviewTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let resultsController = SearchResultsController()
        resultsController.birds = birds
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController)
        //searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true

        let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
        searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["One", "Two"]
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = resultsController
```

and the second class:

```
class SearchResultsController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    var items: [Item] = []
    var filtered: [Item] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

// MARK: - UISearchResultsUpdating Conformance

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    //searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
    let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text
    let buttonIndex = searchController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex
    filtered.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

    if !searchString.isEmpty {
        for item in items {
            ...
            }
        }

    self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

Comment: For your first problem 'a)', are you testing in the Simulator or a device? If in the Simulator, try tapping ⌘K (command-k).

Comment: Also, could you show us some relevant code so that we can help you a bit more? Perhaps some of the delegate/datasource methods of both controllers?

Comment: benhameen - thanks I was able to get the keyboard with the shortcut.

Comment: ...but the second issue remains

Comment: can you post the code of cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Due to the fact that I use a second class for the Search it does not work. I found out that if I use the same OverviewTableViewController for the search results it accesses the same Table View and thus the same cells. So I don't make a resultsSearchController but rather use the following: searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and basically if your parent class has a UISearchController as well as your child class and you're setting the

`self.definesPresentationController = YES`

in your parent class, your child class' search controller won't have the keyboard showing. Took me a while to figure out but this is what is happening.

The way to fix it is to set the `self.definesPresentationController = NO` when your parent class is about to push the child class and set `self.definesPresentationController = YES` in the `viewWillAppear` of your parent class...

Hope this helps someone out there too.

Comment: This did help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> In my main TableView I access the prototype cell that has the style "Subtitle". When the search is going on, the cell that shows is "Basic" style

Make sure that cells in the `SearchResultsController` are also of "Subtitle" style.

Answer (score 0):

Besides doing what the other users suggested, I also did the following, and it worked:

`searchController.definesPresentationContext = true`