# Make UISearchController search bar automatically active

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I've implemented a UISearchController with its search bar in a navigatiom bar and I would like to make the search bar active when the view is loaded. When I say active, I mean that the keyboard appears and the user can type his/her search without tap the search bar.

I initialised the UISearchController with the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    [self.searchController setSearchResultsUpdater:self];
    [self.searchController setDimsBackgroundDuringPresentation:NO];
    [self.searchController setHidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation:NO];
    [self.navigationItem setTitleView:self.searchController.searchBar];

    [self setDefinesPresentationContext:YES];

    [self.searchController.searchBar setDelegate:self];
    [self.searchController.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES];
    [self.searchController.searchBar setPlaceholder:@"City or Airfield"];

    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
}
```

I've tried to make my search controller active, call `[self.searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder]` and directly call `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` but nothing works.

Comment: is searchController code is in viewDidLoad

Comment: Just to make sure if with your current code when you tap the search bar everything works fine ...right? And where did you put '[self.searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder]' in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Yes everything works fine. I first tried in viewDidLoad then in viewDidAppear with both the same result, nothing.

Comment: So you already put '[self.searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder]' after initialising the search bar, correct?

Comment: yes exactly, I've already done that

Comment: This issues have had the solution at link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37848770/3299612

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try calling

```
[self.searchController setActive:YES]
```

before

```
[self.searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder]
```

If the above is not working, try something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...
    [self initializeSearchController];
    ....
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.searchController setActive:YES];
    [self.searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)initializeSearchController {
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];

    [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.searchController.searchBar];
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
}
```

Comment: I still have the same result. What I don't understand is that depsite the fact that I set active to YES, when I print `self.searchController.active` is still set to NO.

Comment: Actually to me, your code looks fine but you may have missed setting Active to search controller. I have updated my answer with splitting up into parts. Hopefully it may help ...just try it out.

Comment: Still the same result. I realised that I forgot to mention that I'm using a modal segue, do you think it could be a problem?

Comment: Hard to say because I don't see the relevant code to that. I'm now rather thinking about what you mentioned earlier that the search controller has never been active despite active setting. So if possible, you may try another approach by adding a subview with search bar and  place it in navigation bar instead.

Comment: It's not work on iOS 9. Here're my solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/37848770/3299612

Comment: it seems working when I added a 1 second delay when calling `becomeFirstResponder`.

Answer (score 8):

To activate the search bar:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.searchController setActive:YES];
}
```

"becomeFistResponder" can be called to make the keyboard appear only when UISearchController is loaded .

```
- (void)didPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    [searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: please dont add plain code as answer. Explain how your answer solves the OP issue.

Comment: Updated with the explanation.

Comment: For some reason, setting `[searchController setActive:YES];` in `viewDidLoad` does not work. This is due to something having to do with `searchController.searchBar` not being fully initialized in some way. There is also the possibility of a view related problem with `searchController.searchBar`. This solution also worked for me.

Comment: I need to add a delay inside `didPresentSearchController` to get it works in iOS 12 simulator.  I added 300ms delay which I think reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

### For those looking for a solution in 2022

I have tried the solution provided here with no luck.

So, here are the three approaches in swift that each seems to work.

- Using delegate, make `Searchcontroller` active in the `main` queue.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var searchController = UISearchController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchController.delegate = self
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        // If this is not called in main queue, the searchbar is not being active
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.searchController.isActive = true
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UISearchControllerDelegate {
    
    func didPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

- Making the searchbar `firstResponder` after some delay.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var searchController = UISearchController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        delay(0.1) { self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder() }
    }
    
    func delay(_ delay: Double, closure: @escaping ()-> Void) {
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
    }
}
```

- Or just making the searchbar `firstResponder` in `main` queue.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var searchController = UISearchController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {  // must call from main thread
            self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The final method worked for me - calling becomeFirstResponder() in main queue was what finally got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Besides doing what the other users suggested, I also did the following, and it worked:

`searchController.definesPresentationContext = YES;`