# UISearchController expands off screen when tapped

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uinavigationitem, uisearchcontroller

We're having a weird issue with using a UISearchController as an item in a navigation bar. It's set as the left bar button item and when a user taps to start searching, the search bar expands to the right off the side of the screen.

Below is the code for creating the UISearchController:

```
resultSearchController = ({
    let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
    controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    controller.searchBar.delegate = self
    controller.delegate = self

    controller.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 266, height: 44.0)
    let searchBarView = UIView(frame: controller.searchBar.frame)
    searchBarView.addSubview(controller.searchBar)

    controller.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "searchBarBG")
    controller.searchBar.barTintColor = .white
    controller.searchBar.subviews[0].subviews.flatMap(){ $0 as? UITextField }.first?.tintColor = Constants.Colors.Red

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: searchBarView)

    return controller
})()
```

When the screen first loads, it looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg8Ar.png)

After tapping on the search bar, it changes to look like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ae9uf.png)

I have no idea what's causing this. After lots of searching, I tried changing `self.definesPresentationContext = false;` and `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true` as well as adjusting similar checkboxes in the storyboard. Any tips?

**Edit:** This only seems to happen on iOS 11. In 10.3, the search bar actually shrinks a little to accommodate the Cancel button but ultimately takes up the same amount of space.

Comment: Does it change if you alter the constants in controller.searchBar.frame?

Comment: It changes the starting size of the search bar, but it still expands out past the side of the screen when tapped.

Comment: Have you checked the constraints on it? Beware of error messages related to the constraints breaking.

Comment: We don't have any constraints on it. It's created programmatically as shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by overriding the `didPresentSearchController` and `didDismissSearchController` methods as part of the `UISearchControllerDelegate`.

```
extension ContactUsViewController: UISearchControllerDelegate {

    func didPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) 
    {
        searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 266, height: 44.0)
    }

    func didDismissSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) 
    {
        searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 266, height: 44.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: This along with https://stackoverflow.com/a/31106630/2704776 helped me to solve - note I had my search controller in a view not the nav bar

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the added functionality of `UISearchBarController` you can directly use `UISearchBar`, which has a more predictable resizing behavor:

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 20))
searchBar.delegate = self
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: searchBar)
```

Note that if you use the built-in cancel button or other similar features you'll have to manually handle them in the delegate methods.