# UISearchController - Search text clear icon does not hide completely

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I am setting up searchController as below in viewDidLoad() in my view controllers. One VC has table view embedded and another is UITableViewController.

I am using another VC to allow user to select a value and use that to filter tables items using unwind segue.

```
self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true

if #available(iOS 11.0, *)  {


    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true            
    self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "<= 2", "<= 5", "<= 10"]

    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true

}
```

i do the below in unwind method.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.searchController.searchBar.text = searchText

                let scope = self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![self.searchController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex]

                self.filterContentForSearchText(searchText, scope: scope)

            }
```

When table with data is loaded, search bar is hidden completely under navigation bar but when i assign value to the searchtext field that doesnt yield any items from data source, the search field clear icon shows as below.

I am using DZNEmptyDataSet framework to handle empty views. Earlier i had configured search bar from IB and at that below issue didnt come. Was using DZNEmptyDataSet at that time also.

[image]

What could be the issue?

Xcode 9.3
Testing in 11.3 simulator and 8 Plus.

Thanks
Ashish

Comment: Try setting `navigationItem.searchController = searchController`

Comment: but i am already doing that.

Comment: oh I must of missed that.

Comment: Try this one for hide search bar : self.navigationController.navigationItem.searchController.active = false;

Comment: No it didn't work but i was able to show the search controller in unwind method  by calling searchController.isActive = true on main queue as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951965/cannot-set-searchbar-as-firstresponder/37848770#37848770. Keeping the question open in case someone is able to suggest a solution.