# Cannot get becomeFirstResponder work on UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

In `viewDidLoad()`:

```
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
let cancelButtonAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(cancelButtonAttributes, for: .normal)

searchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController?.delegate = self
searchController?.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
searchController?.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 0.9)
searchController?.searchBar.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("Search", comment: "")
searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController?.searchBar

searchController?.isActive = true
self.searchController?.becomeFirstResponder()
self.searchController?.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Here is the delegate method:

```
extension SearchMembers :  UISearchControllerDelegate {
    func didPresentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController){
          self.searchController?.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

In my test `didPresentSearchController(searchController:)` is never called.

I don't know why but whatever I do just doesn't work.

Any idea?

EDIT
The only solution that works

```
      delay(0.6) {
         self.searchController?.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
```

Which creates an unwanted lag

Comment: I believe you want this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951965/cannot-set-searchbar-as-firstresponder

Comment: @digitalHound I tried all answers on this page but didn't work

Comment: Use textfield in place of searchbar

Comment: “just doesn't work.” unclear what that means. Work, to do what? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @matt I tried all of those answers on that page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951965/cannot-set-searchbar-as-firstresponder if you know any better please let me know

Comment: I didn’t ask what you tried. I asked what your goal is in the first place. What are you trying to make happen in the app?

Comment: @matt sorry I misread your comment. I have a tableview controller that shows search results and I put a search controller into navigationItem.titleView. I just want it to becomeFirstResponder and show keyboard on viewdidload

Comment: Say `self.searchController?.isActive = true`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontrollerdelegate/1618646-didpresentsearchcontroller) of `didPresentSearchController`:

> This method is only called when the search controller is automatically presented. It is not called if you explicitly present the search controller.

If you want to present the search results interface explicitly, wrap your search controller in a `UISearchContainerViewController` object and present that object instead.

Comment: What does it mean by  automatically presented?

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz Have a look here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller