# Keyboard is appearing and immediately disappearing when UISearchBar.becomeFirstResponder() is getting called

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, swift4.2

I have `UISearchController` in the `navigationItem.searchController` and I want to make it focus when the user selects "Search" from the menu.
So shortly, when the user is tapping on the "Search" option in the menu (`UITableViewCell`) it's getting the view controller that have the `searchController` in it and calling:

```
guard let navigationVC = presentingViewController as? UINavigationController else { return }
guard let documentsVC = navigationVC.topViewController as? DocumentsViewController else { return }
documentsVC.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Then, the `UISearchBar` is getting focus, the keyboard is appearing and then it's immediately disappearing, and I **don't** have any code that would make it disappear (like `view.endEditing()`).

1 GIF is worth more than 1,000 words:
[image: Keyboard is appearing and immediately disappearing when UISearchBar.becomeFirstResponder() is getting called]

Comment: Can you try setting the `isActive` property of the `searchController` to `true` before calling `documentsVC.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()`? Also, make sure that `documentsVC.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()` is called on the main thread.

Comment: Tried that also, didn't work:

 ```documentsVC.searchController.isActive = true
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
     documentsVC.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }```

Comment: I'v noticed that when I'm doing that it's working: ```DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.4) { documentsVC.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder() }```

But I want to do something that wont be lead on specific time, 'Cause right now I'm running this on iPhone X with iOS 12, maybe on other devices with older versions it will need more time.

Comment: I think this means that the SearchController is still not fully loaded when you call `documentVC.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder`. Did you try doing the same thing but inside `viewDidAppear` of `documentsViewController`? I hope that this can point you to what could be the problem.

Comment: It's only getting "active", but the keyboard doesn't appears (when I'm calling the code from `viewDidAppear`). This is the issue, I don't know how to detect when the `searchBar` is ready to `becomeFirstResponder`.

Comment: Can you check if the UISearchController delegate method `didPresentSearchController'` is called after you set `documentsVC.searchController.isActive = true` in `viewDidAppear`? I think inside `didPresentSearchController` delegate method you can call `documentsVC.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()`. The search controller should be fully loaded by that time. I found also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951965/cannot-set-searchbar-as-firstresponder/28527114) that maybe helpful for you.

Comment: Also in `didPresentSearchController`, `documentsVC.searchController.searchBar.canBecomeFirstResponder` is `false` so I can't use `documentsVC.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()`.

Comment: I'v posted some workaround for this problem, if you have some better way, please feel free to post answer with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after many tries I got some way to make it work, but I'm sure there is a much more elegant ways to do this, so **if someone think that they have better way, please post it here** and I may use it and mark your answer as the correct one.

Create the function `focusOnSearchBar()` in `YourViewController`:

```
func focusOnSearchBar() {
  let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
  if searchBar.canBecomeFirstResponder {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
  } else {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
      self.focusOnSearchBar()
    }
  }
}
```

What it actually do is use itself recursively and check (every 0.1 sec) if `searchBar.canBecomeFirstResponder`. **This is the problematic/not elegant thing.**

Then, add this to `viewDidAppear()`:

```
if focusOnSearch {
  searchController.isActive = true
}
```

Don't forget to add extension to your ViewController for `UISearchControllerDelegate` (and of course, set `searchController.delegate = self`) and implement `didPresentSearchController` (that will be invoke by setting `searchController.isActive = true`):

```
extension YourViewController: UISearchControllerDelegate {
  func didPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
    if focusOnSearch {
      focusOnSearchBar()
    }
  }
}
```

Now all you have to do is to set `focusOnSearch = true` in the `prepare(for segue:sender:)`.

***Note:** if you want to focusOnSearchBar **while you are in the same `viewController`** of the `searchBar`, just set:

```
 focusOnSearch = true
 searchController.isActive = true
```

And it will work by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Make your searchbar first responder in the viewDidLoad method. That will make sure everything is ready before focusing the search bar.

Comment: When I'm calling it in `viewDidLoad()` it doesn't even focus on the `searchBar` like it did in the GIF, nothing happening.