# How to focus search bar on barbutton click?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am trying to autofocus a searchbar when i click on a bar button, but it does not seem to work with `becomeFirstResponder`, follow the GIF:

[image: Example]

I've already tried using `becomeFirstResponder` and it does not work, this is how i am handling the searchbar:

```
// MARK: SearchBar Delegate
    @IBAction func showSearchBarAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.searchBar.keyboardAppearance = .dark
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        navigationItem.searchController?.isActive = true
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        navigationItem.searchController?.isActive = false
        self.navigationItem.searchController = nil
    }
```

All of it works perfectly, but the autofocus is something i really want and i can't change my design as well

**Solution**

This code is the solution:

[image: Example]

This is how my class declaration looks like:

```
class YourViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate {
```

```
// MARK: SearchBar Delegate
    @IBAction func showSearchBarAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.searchBar.keyboardAppearance = .dark
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        self.navigationItem.searchController?.isActive = true
    }

    func didPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        navigationItem.searchController?.isActive = false
        self.navigationItem.searchController = nil
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951965/cannot-set-searchbar-as-firstresponder

Comment: Sometimes it's just because the keyboard does not show when you run the Simulator. Check by toggling the software keyboard: hit command+K when you think the keyboard should be displayed (Hardware -> Keyboard -> Toggle Software Keyboard in Simulator).

Comment: I've built it on my iphone and the same happens :(

Comment: Thank you so much cora and David, i found the answer, i'll update the question with the solution